# How to get the 'ng-repeat'(ed) button text string to the next page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm developing a Ionic mobile app & I want to pass the button text (which I'll be getting in a `ng-repeat`) as a string value to the next page and display the variable in the title bar. How do I achieve this? I tried so many solutions from the web resources but still no luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <div ng-repeat="x in list">
        <button ng-click="callCustomFn(x.text)">
         {{x.text}}
        </button>
    </div>
```

Create some service and set its custom variable value to the button text clicked from controller and access it in next page

Your controller :-

```
$scope.callCustomFn = function(text){
  myService.setText(text);
}
```

Inside new page controller :-

```
$scope.title = myService.getText();
```